# How do I add the same CSS property (e.g. background-image) multiple times with React?

Tags: css, reactjs

I want to do the equivalent of `style="background-image: url(foo.jpg); background-image: -webkit-image-set(url(foo_1x.jpg) 1x, url(foo_2x.jpg) 2x)"` in a React component.

React requires me to provide a style object, not a string. But a JS object can't have the same property twice.

How do I get two `background-image` properties? Also, the order is significant – the image-set needs to be last.

It needs to be an inline style. (Because the URL is a dynamic, interpolated value retrieved from DB.)

Comment: Have you tried a background image list? `style="background-image: url(foo.jpg),-webkit-image-set(url(foo_1x.jpg) 1x, url(foo_2x.jpg) 2x)"` Or are you asking how to do this with React's `style` prop? I'm a little unsure what you are asking for.

Comment: @DrewReese Ah, sorry if I was unclear. Yes, asking how to do with React's style prop which requires me to pass an object rather than a string. I have tried stuff like passing an array (`style={ backgroundImage: [ … ] }` (no luck) and including both in one `background-image` property the way you described. The latter almost works but either the non-image-set URL "wins" in WebKit or there's no image at all in non-WebKit (e.g. Firefox) depending on which order I choose.

Comment: @HenrikN could you please share the use case of using two background-images? Maybe a workaround could be found around that. Using an object won't be a solution.

Comment: @VinaySharma I want to intelligently get 1x or 2x images in browsers that support (-webkit-)image-set to balance bandwidth/resolution, with a 1x fallback for other browsers such as Firefox. I'm considering making it not-a-bg-image as a workaround – but would still be nice to know how to achieve this in React.

Comment: Does it absolutely need to be an inline-style prop object? If you could do CSS-in-JS and write your CSS ***as*** CSS and pass props to it, could something like [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/) work for you?

Comment: @DrewReese Thank you! The image URLs need to be dynamic (retrieved from DB) – if something like styled-components allows for that, it could be an option. Would be nice not to have to introduce a new dependency and a new way of doing CSS if it can be avoided, of course.

Comment: Reported it as a bug: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/20757

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"spassvogel" on GitHub has a clever solution using CSS variables: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/20757#issuecomment-776191029

The idea is to set CSS variables in the `style` property, like

```
style={ "--url1": "url(1.jpg)", "--url2": "url(2.jpg)" }
```

and then using them from an external style sheet, like

```
background-image: var(--url1);
```

and so on.

Turns out this still wasn't enough to solve everything I wanted – this rabbit hole [runs ever deeper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66127664/why-does-firefox-try-to-use-an-otherwise-invalid-background-image-declaration-wh) – but that's no fault of React's, so I'll consider this a valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think I initially misunderstood your question. Seems you are looking to create a style object to pass as a prop to a component. You can combine your background images into a single comma separated list. You can use a string template to inject the dynamic image urls at runtime.

```
const style = {
  backgroundImage: `url(${url1}),-webkit-image-set(url(${url2}) 1x, url(${url3}) 2x)`,
};
```

Comment: Thank you. As per my comment above, this *almost* works but either the non-image-set URL "wins" in WebKit or there's no image at all in non-WebKit (e.g. Firefox) depending on which order I choose. Seems it needs to render as two separate "background-image" properties.

Comment: Right, we responded at nearly the same time. Ok, I'll need to think about this for a bit.