# Why does the browser try to use an otherwise invalid property declaration when I introduce a CSS variable?

Tags: css, css-variables

I use two background-image declarations like this to get a fallback:

```
background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/300x150.png?text=regular);
background-image: -webkit-image-set(
  url(https://via.placeholder.com/300x150.png?text=1x) 1x,
  url(https://via.placeholder.com/600x300.png?text=2x) 2x
);
```

JS bin: https://jsbin.com/jadoharoyi/edit?html,css,output

The idea is for e.g. Firefox to show the "regular" bg because it doesn't support -webkit-image-set, and for e.g. Chrome to show the "1x" or "2x" bg (depending on resolution) because it *does* support -webkit-image-set.

So far so good.

But if I try to provide one or more of the image URLs via CSS variables (for [convoluted reasons](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/20757)), it falls down:

```
--image-1x: url(https://via.placeholder.com/300x150.png?text=1x);

background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/300x150.png?text=regular);
background-image: -webkit-image-set(
  var(--image-1x) 1x,
  url(https://via.placeholder.com/600x300.png?text=2x) 2x
);
```

JS bin: https://jsbin.com/vojiboqije/1/edit?html,css,output

Now, Firefox (85.0.2 on macOS Big Sur 11.1) doesn't show a bg image at all. As far as I can tell, Firefox is suddenly happy to try to use the second background-image declaration, which it doesn't support.

But it works fine in Chrome (88.0.4324.146).

I don't understand why. Any ideas? Is this a bug? Or a misunderstanding on my part?

Comment: On the assumption that this is a Firefox issue, I filed a bug report: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1691833

Comment: making the title more generic since it's not only related to Firefox or a particular property

Comment: Meanwhile Firefox is supporting `image-set()`. Since FF version 90 Firefox internally links `image-set()` to `-webkit-image-set` to provide compatibility with sites omitting the W3C-conform variant.

Comment: If you use `image-set()` with variables and want to support the W3C-variant, you have to write the variant  `-webkit-image-set(var(--img) 1x)` **after** the version `image-set(var(--img) 1x)`. Else WebKit based browsers like Chrome and Edge will not display the image (currently). — Obviously triggered by the variable evaluation described in the answer here. As Firefox also accepts the WebKit version FF has no problem due to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This how CSS variables are meant to work. When using CSS variables the browser can only evalute the value at run-time so the value will be considered as valid (or lets say in a standby mode) until we evalute the variable and if the browser find the whole value invalid, it will fallback to initial or inherit:

> A declaration can be invalid at computed-value time if it contains a var() that references a custom property with its initial value, as explained above, or **if it uses a valid custom property, but the property value, after substituting its var() functions, is invalid.** When this happens, the computed value of the property is either the property’s inherited value or its initial value depending on whether the property is inherited or not, respectively, as if the property’s value had been specified as the unset keyword. <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/)</sup>

A more explicit example with a clearly non valid value:

```css
html {
  background:linear-gradient(red,blue); /* this will be used */
  background:strange-gradient(red,blue); /* this is a joke */
  
  min-height:100%;
}
```

And when using CSS variable, the second one will be used unfortunately making your first instruction useless.

```css
html {
  --c:red;

  background:linear-gradient(red,blue);  /* this will be ignored */
  background:strange-gradient(var(--c),blue); /* the joke is being used ..*/
  
  min-height:100%;
}
```

---

This behavior is somehow logical since by changing a variable we can make a value valid (if it was previously invalid) or invalid (if it was previously valid) so the browser should consider it.

---

For your particular case you can consider pseudo element trick:

```css
.my-div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
  
  --image-1x: url(https://via.placeholder.com/300x150.png?text=1x);

  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/300x150.png?text=regular);
}
/* the pseudo element will cover the main background if it's valid */
.my-div::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background-image: -webkit-image-set(
    var(--image-1x) 1x,
    url(https://via.placeholder.com/600x300.png?text=2x) 2x
  );
}
```

```html
<div class="my-div">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Brilliant answer. Very well explained. I guess I could possibly achieve my goal by relying on inheritance for the fallback, then.

Comment: @HenrikN added a fix to your particular case

Comment: Thank you for the pseudo-element snippet. I'm afraid it shows "regular" in Chrome rather than the expected "1x" or "2x". I think the sane thing for me to do here would be to give up on background images and use a solution with <img srcset> instead, but it's been very educational :)

Comment: @HenrikN I made a copy/past mistake .. I was confident with my answer that I didn't even try it :p

Comment: Found this additional reference about how invalid variables are handled: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties#what_happens_with_invalid_variables And that code seems to work as expected now. Thank you!

Comment: Just realised – a major downside of that pseudo-element workaround is that it will presumably load both the fallback image and the non-fallback image when -webkit-image-set is supported, even if you don't need the fallback. Which goes a bit against the idea of using -webkit-image-set to load only the correct image for the user's circumstances.

Comment: Ah! Think I cracked it. I can use a CSS variable only for the fallback background, and do the non-fallback one as an inline style: https://jsbin.com/kobivatuzo/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Oops, updated "cracked it" JS bin that actually uses a CSS variable: https://jsbin.com/hisuxudusi/1/edit?html,css,output