# Overriding CSS variable with the same name doesn't work until assigned to a different variable?

Tags: css, css-variables

I've been playing about with CSS variables and their fallbacks and have come across something I can't explain.

I can define a variable and assign it to another variable with a fallback (.p1)
I can define a variable, assign it to itself further down the DOM, and then assign it to a new variable (.p3)
But assigning a variable to itself doesn't actually render (.p2) despite devtools showing me the property is working

[image]

```css
main {
    --box-one-top: #00ff00;
    --box-two-top: #00ff00;
    --box-three-top: #00ff00;
}

.article {
    --box-one-bottom: var(--box-one-top, #ff0000);
    --box-two-top: var(--box-two-top, #ff0000);
    --box-three-top: var(--box-two-top, #ff0000);
}

.p1 {
    background-color: var(--box-one-bottom);
}
    
.p2 {
    background-color: var(--box-two-top);
}
    
.p3 {
    background-color: var(--box-three-top);
}
```

```html
<main>
    <article class="article">
        <p class="p1">Box 1</p>
        <p class="p2">Box 2</p>
        <p class="p3">Box 3</p>
    </article>
</main>
```

Comment: Why are you defining a variable as itself? That's just not logical. It's hardly surprising that does not work.

Comment: the duplicate explain why you cannot do this and read this to understand why the browser still think it's good: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66127994/8620333