# Is property redeclaration in CSS selector query always equivalent to just the very last property declaration?

Tags: css, sass, less

I'm investigating how modern CSS preprocessors behave and noticed that both SASS and LESS actually do nothing when encounter property redeclaration in the same query, For instance this code (valid in both of above-mentioned preprocessors):

```css
.some {
  color: red;
  color: yellow;
  color: maroon;
}
```

will be translated exactly the same way, without changes, that is, we'll get, again:

```css
.some {
  color: red;
  color: yellow;
  color: maroon;
}
```

My question would be - are there any CSS properties that make sense to be declared in the same selector query N times where the effect of this declaration is not equivalent to just leaving the very last declaration (in this case - `color: maroon`).

Keep in mind that I'm not necessarily asking why preprocessor were designed this way. If there are such properties, than it will be the answer. If there are not, it can make sense for some other reasons, say, performance which is out of scope of this question.

Comment: One use case would be if you need a fallback for a property. e.g.: If you are using a css custom property but you also want to support browser who don't support them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose, in cases where you're asking for property considered as invalid by some browser.
For instance:

```
.some {
  background:  background: rgb(61,217,0);
  background:  linear-gradient(328deg, rgba(61,217,0,1) 0%, rgba(12,242,187,1) 100%);
}
```

Also, in the case you're using a fetched image, you may be able to show it along a background color, [as shown there](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background) or here:

```
.some {
  background: var(--fallback-color)  url('https://possibly.dead.com/but/pretty_img');
}
```

So, if the link is dead, the background color still shows up.

Comment: your example doesn't stand because all the browsers support an image as background

Comment: @TemaniAfif even if so I can clearly see that this is a valid idea. Yep, in this particular case all properties are supported for quite a while but the main idea of the answer holds true. So personally I upvoted.

Comment: Here's the example that the CSS 2 spec gives: https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/#example-2d9f483a

Comment: @TemaniAfif my example was supposed to show that if the link is dead, a fallback property would be used by the browser.

Comment: no, if the link is dead the browser will not use the previous property. A dead link will not make the property invalid

Comment: the last example is worse because introducing a CSS variable will trigger another complex behavior and the property will never be invalid: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66127994/8620333

Comment: @shabunc check my comments to understand why this answer is "misleading" and will create a confusion

Comment: what do you think of my correction?