# css --variable strange behavior whith multiple use

Tags: html, css

This css working OK

```
.my_div{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 200px;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    border: solid 1px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.bg1{
    background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(center center, circle contain, #fedc3f 0%, #ff7420 100%);
    background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(center center, circle contain, #fedc3f 0%, #ff7420 100%);
    background-image: radial-gradient(center center, circle contain, #fedc3f 0%, #ff7420 100%);
}
```

html

```
<div class="my_div bg1">
    .bg1
</div>
```

If I try `:root{--color2: 23;}` and `background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(center center, circle contain, #fedc3f 0%, hsla(var(--color2), 100%, 56%, 1) 100%);` it's ok too.

but if I add another line with `-moz-radial-gradient` or `-o-radial-gradient` or `ms-radial-gradient` or simply `radial-gradient` with `hsla(var(--color2), 100%, 56%, 1)` that fail in all navigators

**See code snippet for live results:**

```css
:root{
    --color2: 23;
}

.my_div{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 200px;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    border: solid 1px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.bg1{
    background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(center center, circle contain, #fedc3f 0%, hsla(var(--color2), 100%, 56%, 1) 100%);
    background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(center center, circle contain, #fedc3f 0%, #ff7420 100%);
    background-image: radial-gradient(center center, circle contain, #fedc3f 0%, #ff7420 100%);
}

.bg2{
    background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(center center, circle contain, #fedc3f 0%, hsla(var(--color2), 100%, 56%, 1) 100%);
    background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(center center, circle contain, #fedc3f 0%, hsla(var(--color2), 100%, 56%, 1) 100%);
    background-image: radial-gradient(center center, circle contain, #fedc3f 0%, #ff7420 100%);
}

.bg3{
    background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(center center, circle contain, #fedc3f 0%, hsla(var(--color2), 100%, 56%, 1) 100%);
    background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(center center, circle contain, #fedc3f 0%, #ff7420 100%);
    background-image: radial-gradient(center center, circle contain, #fedc3f 0%, hsla(var(--color2), 100%, 56%, 1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="my_div bg1">
    .bg1
</div>
<div class="my_div bg2">
    .bg2
</div>
<div class="my_div bg3">
    .bg3
</div>
```

**I have tried also :**

```
:root{
    --color2: 23;
    --compozite-color: hsla(var(--color2), 100%, 56%, 1);
}
```

And in css for multiple navigators not working ... only work for one

**This work:**

```
background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(center center, circle contain, #fedc3f 0%, var(--compozite-color) 100%);
```

**This NOT WORK:** (nor in webkit that worked before)

```
background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(center center, circle contain, #fedc3f 0%, var(--compozite-color) 100%);
background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(center center, circle contain, #fedc3f 0%, var(--compozite-color) 100%);
```

**I have tried also (but not work):**

```
.bg_webkit{
    background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(center center, circle contain, #fedc3f 0%, hsla(var(--color2), 100%, 56%, 1) 100%);
}

.bg_moz{    
    background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(center center, circle contain, #fedc3f 0%, hsla(var(--color2), 100%, 56%, 1) 100%); 
}

.bg{
    background-image: radial-gradient(center center, circle contain, #fedc3f 0%, hsla(var(--color2), 100%, 56%, 1) 100%);
}
```

...

```
<div class="my_div bg_webkit bg_moz bg">
    .bg1
</div>
<div class="my_div bg_webkit bg_moz bg">
    .bg2
</div>
<div class="my_div bg_webkit bg_moz bg">
    .bg3
</div>
```

**This (for only one navigator) work (but it doesn't help me)**

```
<div class="my_div bg_webkit">
    .bg1
</div>
```

Comment: The unprefixed one should be `radial-gradient(circle closest-side at center center, #fedc3f 0%, hsla(var(--color2), 100%, 56%, 1) 100%)`; I will write a detailed explanation later.

Comment: The issue is not the variable custom property, the issue is an invalid value for `background-image: radial-gradient()`. (This error is shown in Developer Tools.) qrsngky commented with the correct value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short Answer:

The CSS declaration (unprefixed version) should be:

`background-image: radial-gradient(circle closest-side at center center, #fedc3f 0%, hsla(var(--color2), 100%, 56%, 1) 100%);`

---

## More explanation:

Your original declaration `background-image: radial-gradient(center center, circle contain, #fedc3f 0%, #ff7420 100%);` is not valid. It does not match the description [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/radial-gradient).

I googled `"center center, circle contain"` and found [this link](https://www.impressivewebs.com/css3-radial-gradient-syntax/) which says **the syntax for radial gradients has changed** (that was 2012, by the way).
So, while `-webkit-radial-gradient` and `-moz-radial-gradient` still support the old syntax, `radial-gradient` doesn't.

However, (in the case where there is no variable), when that invalid syntax is encountered, the browser will ignore it. For example, in Chrome, as you can see from the Developer Tools, what is applied to `.bg1` is `background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(center center, circle contain, #fedc3f 0%, hsla(var(--color2), 100%, 56%, 1) 100%);`.[image]
Note that it also ignores the `-moz-radial-gradient` one.

However, when there is a variable, it will not "simply ignore the invalid value". Instead, it uses the property value with a variable anyway (overriding the previous values), and only fails after substituting (see [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66127664/why-does-the-browser-try-to-use-an-otherwise-invalid-property-declaration-when-i)).

That also explains why `.bg2` does not work in Chrome (it tries to load `-moz-radial-gradient` then fails), but it works in Firefox anyway.

And `.bg3` does not work for Chrome and Firefox, as both will try to use your unprefixed `radial-gradient(...)` and fail.

So, the solution is to use a valid value for the unprefixed one. You can replace `center center, circle contain` with `circle closest-side at center center`.

Also, since you are using `var()`, that means you don't need to use `-moz-radial-gradient` or `-webkit-radial-gradient` anymore. By checking [caniuse: "radial-gradient"](https://caniuse.com/?search=radial-gradient) and [caniuse: "custom properties"](https://caniuse.com/?search=custom%20properties), we can see that `radial-gradient` is supported even earlier than `var` (except that we lack data for "radial-gradient" for some less common browsers, greyed out in the link above)

```css
:root{
    --color2: 23;
}

.my_div{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 200px;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    border: solid 1px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.bg4{
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle closest-side at center center, #fedc3f 0%, hsla(var(--color2), 100%, 56%, 1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="my_div bg4">
    .bg4
</div>
```

(And in case someone is curious about the case of 'cover', `center center, circle cover` should be replaced with `circle farthest-corner at center center`)

Answer (score 0):

```css
:root {
  --color2: 23;
}

.my_div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid 1px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.bg_color {
  background-color: hsla(var(--color2), 100%, 56%, 1);
}

.bg1 {
background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(center center, circle contain, #fedc3f 0%, hsla(var(--color2), 100%, 56%, 1) 100%);
background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(center center, circle contain, #fedc3f 0%, hsla(var(--color2), 100%, 56%, 1) 100%);
background-image: radial-gradient(center center, circle contain, #fedc3f 0%, hsla(var(--color2), 100%, 56%, 1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="my_div bg_color bg1">.bg1</div>
<div class="my_div bg_color bg1">.bg2</div>
<div class="my_div bg_color bg1">.bg3</div>
```

Comment: I have used `bg1, bg2, bg3` only for showing the issue but I need `bg1` css to work with all navigators in one div using `--color2` variable instead `#ff7420`

Comment: If I am understanding you right. What you can do is just use bg1 for all the divs then, and  delete the other bgs. it will still render.

Comment: No. You dont't understand me. I need only one div with one css but using css variable as color not fixed html color for all navigators

Comment: so you want a var in the place of this color `#fedc3f`?

Comment: So `hsla(23, 100%, 56%, 1)` is the same as `#ff7420`
I need to use `--color2` variable only instead `23` (hue)
like `hsla(var(--color2), 100%, 56%, 1)`

Comment: Something like: `background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(center center, circle contain, #fedc3f 0%, hsla(var(--color2), 100%, 56%, 1) 100%); background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(center center, circle contain, #fedc3f 0%, hsla(var(--color2), 100%, 56%, 1) 100%); background-image: radial-gradient(center center, circle contain, #fedc3f 0%, hsla(var(--color2), 100%, 56%, 1) 100%);`
But not work

Comment: oh im sorry, I accidently removed this in my first edit "The issue is that not all browsers support CSS vars in the background image. so you cant use the var for the color.". the reason it was not working, and cant do what you are asking is because, the -moz-radial-gradient, cant have a css vars.

Comment: No. I don't think this is it. I think it's a bug. The fact that mozilla doesn't support variables doesn't have to affect other browsers (I've tested on chrome and edge). So the issue is if I add more of one line. even if the second line is this `background-image: radial-gradient(center center, circle contain, #fedc3f 0%, hsla(var(--color2), 100%, 56%, 1) 100%);` So nothing about mozilla

Comment: Trying it in a hurry this morning I thought your solution works, but I was wrong. The gradient does not come out. Only an opaque color comes out (which wasn't a problem for me).
So unfortunately ( for me ) I think this is a bug ! thanks for trying to help. The only option I have left is to detect the type of browser and put only one line